# What's the difference between these two listeners?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what the difference is between the two listeners inside the for each that i have in my example code. Can someone please explain?

```
const lists = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list')]

lists.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', onEnter.bind(this))
})

lists.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', onEnter)
})
```

Comment: Not much, as `this` isn't bound on entry into a `=>` function. Why do you think there would be a difference? Do the two versions behave differently?

Comment: I found the one using ´this´ in a project im working on and got curious. it behaves the same. was thinking i was missing out on some fundamental stuff or so..

Comment: Are you sure it's `onEnter.bind(this)`? It should be `onEnter.bind(el)`

Comment: The difference really depends on (a) if `onEnter` uses `this` in the first place, (b) how `onEnter` is defined, and (c) what the value of `this` is in the snippet of code you've provided (which depends on if it is in a function (and how that function is called) or in strict mode etc.

Comment: @Pointy — Well, `this` is bound in `=>` functions, it's bound lexically. It's non-arrow functions where the value is determined when the function is called.

Comment: @Quentin But it's not bound to the current element of the `forEach()` loop, which is what I think they meant.

Comment: @Quentin yes yes, of course, but it's *probably* the case here that it makes no difference. I think the most likely thing is Barmar's suggestion that `this` was supposed to be `el`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the first version actually uses `onEnter.bind(el)`, not `onEnter.bind(this)`.

If so, there shouldn't be any difference.

As explained in [The value of "this" within the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler):

> When attaching a handler function to an element using `addEventListener()`, the value of `this` inside the handler will be a reference to the element. It will be the same as the value of the `currentTarget` property of the event argument that is passed to the handler.

So when `onEnter` is called in the second version of your code, `el` will be passed as the value of `this`. Binding the function to `this` has the same effect.

If my above assumption is not correct, then the only way they would have similar effects is if `onEnter` doesn't use `this`. In the first version, `this` inside the function will be the value of `this` in the context where the loop is running; in the second version it will be `el`.

Comment: `this` won't be `el` at the point it is passed to `bind` (all else being equal, it will probably be `window`).

Comment: Oops, I thought they did `onEnter.nbind(el)`

Comment: I've update the answer so it's "correct" either way.